# how can i get the value on ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED: {'text': 'what you doing Google'} Google Assistant SDK Ubilinux UP2 Board

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, google-assistant-sdk

how can i get the value on `ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED:
  {'text': 'what you doing Google'}` in google assistant

```
ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED
ON_END_OF_UTTERANCE
ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED:
  {'text': 'what you doing Google'}
ON_RESPONDING_STARTED:
  {'is_error_response': False}
ON_RESPONDING_FINISHED
ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_FINISHED:
  {'with_follow_on_turn': False}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you're using that generated that output? or where the output came from? It is very difficult to understand what you're trying to do or what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, from your snippet, you are using the [`hotword.py` sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/library/hotword.py). You can look at the source code to see how it is printing this information:

```
def process_event(event, device_id):
    """Pretty prints events.
    Prints all events that occur with two spaces between each new
    conversation and a single space between turns of a conversation.
    Args:
        event(event.Event): The current event to process.
        device_id(str): The device ID of the new instance.
    """
    if event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED:
        print()

    print(event)

    if (event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_FINISHED and
            event.args and not event.args['with_follow_on_turn']):
        print()
    if event.type == EventType.ON_DEVICE_ACTION:
        for command, params in process_device_actions(event, device_id):
            print('Do command', command, 'with params', str(params))
```

You can pull values from the event args object when you get that event type.

```
if (event.type == EventType.ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED):
    userUtterance = event.args['text']
```